# Changing the UIPageViewController transition

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uipageviewcontroller

I'd like to use an horizontal `UIPageViewController` for my iOS 5.0 application.

The only problem I have is that I don't want a `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl` transition. Is there a way to get a classic transition like translation for example?

Note :Even ugly hacks are accepted since it would take out a lot of my previous code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to tell you that now there is now a new transition style for iOS 6, and it's the transition you wanted

UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

Comment: UIPageViewController handle memory managment so I load only 3 viewControllers at a time even if I have a list of 50 pages.

Comment: With the UIScrollerView you can load 3 (the previous, current and next) and can unload the rest, maybe it's a bit more work because you have to do it "manually", but still don't see the point of using a UIPageViewController only because it handles memory management

Comment: I did the code you are talking about and I'd like to get rid of it as UIPageViewController is exactly doing what I want to do (except for this animation). Less code, means less maintenance so I'm trying to remove as much code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

But UIPageViewController has only one transition style:

```
 enum {
  UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl = 0
 };
 typedef NSInteger UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle;
```

Solution is that u will have to create UIPageViewController like viewController with custom transition

Refer [MPFoldTransition](https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition) sample code

Comment: I know that you can change the push transition of a navigationController by adding a CATTransition to an UINavigationController. Maybe there is also a way to change the transition of a UIPageViewController by using this, no ?